# Typedef—why is this C++ code valid?

Tags: c++, stl

Here's some code written in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    typedef map<int,int> b;
    b tC;

    b::iterator iMap;
    b().swap(tC);
}
```

I've tried:
`b.swap(tc);`
but I keep getting an error.

What I can't understand is, why can't it be `b.swap(tC);` ?

Is this a compiler problem?

Sorry about my English.

Comment: It's equivalent to `map<int,int>.swap(tC);`. You don't expect that to work, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b::swap(x)` (but not `b.swap(x)`!) would have worked if `swap()` was a static class method. But `swap()` is an instance method, and as such, can only work on instance of an object of class `b` (which is `typedef` of `map<int,int>`).

`b().swap(x)` does not emit an error because it works on instance of object of class `b`. However, this call is not likely to be useful, because this instance `b()` is immediately destroyed after instantiating.

Comment: If swap() would have been a static method,then the call should be b::swap(x)

Comment: Thanks - fixed. This is valid for Java, and too much Java can clog your mind! :)

Answer (score 9):

Because `b` is a type. You can't call `swap` on a type. You need to build an object of type `b` and then call `swap` on it, which is what you do with `b().swap(tC);`

This line `typedef map<int,int> b;` is creating a new type called `b`, which has the properties of `map<int,int>`. Thus, in order to use type `b` and objects of type `b` you must follow the same rules as if you were using class `map<int,int>`.

In class `map`, function `swap` is a member function. That's why you need an object in order to use it. If it were a static  function, you could call it directly on the type, although the syntax for that is a little different: `b::static_function()`

Comment: As there are already many answers, i will just add this as a comment here: It seems that the sannim is rather a beginner and thus it may be worth explaining why b is a type, or better explain the general meaning of typedef

Answer (score 3):

Because member functions can only be called via an object, you need to create an object, before calling `swap` on it. Therefore in:

```
b().swap(tC);
```

you are correctly creating a temporary object and swapping it with `tC`.

Comment: I guess this line sounds strange - "Because b is a class, and as such does not have member functions."